# extrem slowness of software updater

Tags: 16.04, lts

I have two pc's served by the same high speed internet connection. For the last few months updating query of sources are extremely slow. it can take 5 minutes or more to get a download list. the slider used to flash back and forth very quickly now it crawls slowly. what happened? Both pc's are using ubuntu 16.04 with 64 bit os.

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contents?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry. Can you instruct me? Also when updates start installing they are extremely slow. It takes about one half hour to update the software.

Comment: If this is the *only* slow network activity, then try a different mirror. Change mirrors using the "Software & Updates" control panel.

Comment: what the heck is a mirror? I looked through the software and updates  files and don't see anything like that.

Comment: @harlie that's ok.  Check my answer, maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that the mirror you are installing from is slow.  Ubuntu gives you the option of which server you want updates to come from.

Find the Software Sources screen (try searching for it from the launcher if necessary).

[image]

Where it says **Download from:** select a different source.  Try one of the main country ones, but not the same one you already had selected.

Comment: I tried several other mirrors none are any faster same problem.